# convert multiple rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Source:

| ItemId | ItemName | Nutrient | GAV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Beef | Vit A | 1 |
| A | Beef | Vit B | 2 |
| A | Beef | Vit C | 3 |

target:

| Id | Name | Nut1 | GAV1 | Nut2 | GAV2 | Nut3 | GAV3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Beef | VitA | 1 | VitB | 2 | VitC | 3 |

How can we achieve this with ms-sql query?

Comment: You should tag ONLY the DBMS you are using, not all of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `GAV` is NOT sequential as presented, we'll have to use the window function  `row_number()` and some Dynamic SQL

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ec794798523a9344dbf14abe4218c23)**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)

Select @SQL = string_agg( concat('[',ColName,ColNr,']','=','max(case when ColNr =',ColNr,' then ',ColName,' end)') , ',') within group (ORDER BY ColNr,ColName Desc)
  From  (values ('Nutrient'),('GAV') ) A(ColName)
  Cross Join ( Select Distinct ColNr = row_number() over( partition by ItemID order by GAV) from YourTable ) B

Set @SQL = '
Select ItemID
      ,ItemName
      ,' + @SQL + '
 From ( Select *
              ,ColNr = row_number() over( partition by ItemID order by GAV )
         From  YourTable
      ) A
 Group By ItemID
         ,ItemName
'

Exec(@SQL)
```

**Results**

[image]

**UPDATE 2016 Version**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''

Select @SQL = @SQL +  concat(',','[',ColName,ColNr,']','=','max(case when ColNr =',ColNr,' then ',ColName,' end)') 
 From  (values ('Nutrient'),('GAV') ) A(ColName)
 Cross Join ( Select Distinct ColNr = row_number() over( partition by ItemID order by GAV) from YourTable ) B
 Order By ColNr,ColName Desc


Set @SQL = '
Select ItemID
      ,ItemName
      ' + @SQL + '
 From ( Select *
              ,ColNr = row_number() over( partition by ItemID order by GAV )
         From  YourTable
      ) A
 Group By ItemID
         ,ItemName
'

Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: I am using 2016 version, do we have any alternative for string_agg please

Comment: @Learner See Update 2016 Version  or https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=db8722125c173f3dd31ed8d61537ed4d